# Reading smart card in Java and capturing the data

Tags: java, smartcard-reader

I am developing a software to POS device using java.Now I am struct on the card reader functionality.I have a card reader which is connected via USB to POS device, and I got  card data within notepad when I swipe the card.

I want get card data to my application when I swipe the card.But I have no idea to implement this on my application.

I would highly appreciate your help with any code samples.

Comment: When you say you get the card data in Notepad when you swipe, does it mean the card reader behaves like a keyboard? In that case, reading the data in Java would be really easy. I have seen barcode readers working like that.

Comment: You swipe the smart card? Are you trying to read the data from the magnetic strip, or are you actually trying to communicate with a smart (chip) card?

Comment: When I swipe the card I get a Number to notepad.So I need to add this for my java application.And when swipe the card ,card number just sent to a server through web service.

Answer (score 0):

If the device acts as a keyboard, you can use any console application or GUI application that accepts keyboard input. This seems logical, so are there any specific points where you get "struct"?